# If the chance of picking a red ball is 5%, what's the chances if 3 balls are picked, are they all red?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The ball is not replaced from where it is picked from.  There is always a $5\%$ chance you will pick a red ball.

Is it $0.05\times0.05\times0.05$?

Comment: Yes. It's a funny selection of balls you have though, such that not replacing one doesn't change the probabilities.

Comment: @SiliconCelery: It's an infinite ball heat bath :-)

Comment: haha yes it is funny... I have used different percentages and a different item from the real question.  I don't know if I'm allowed to ask questions on here or not... so thought it safest to change the data.  The real data is much more realistic.

Comment: Also specify in advance that the three choices are independent.

Comment: Ah ok.  No problem.  Probability is not my strong point.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: ))) ehehe it is really funny. Everywhere there are some red balls with some probability ohh perhaps some pink ones too!

Answer (score 1):

To be serious for a second, drawing balls without replacement are naturally going to be considered independent draws.  If you start with 5% red balls and draw a red then since you do not repace you have less than 5% red balls for the second draw.  Also if you do not pick red you then have more than 5% red balls to select from.  An exact answer cannot be given without knowing N the total number of balls to draw from. If N is very large the probability will be less than but close to (0.05)$^3$.